# Is it possible to append CSS transform properties using Sass?

Tags: css, sass, transform

In this contrived example I have an object to which I am applying a transform. I'd like to be able to add another transform to it by adding another class.

```
.translated{
  @include transform(translateX(50%));
  // This line will write all the vendor prefixed transform properies
  // e.g. -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
  &.rotated{
    @include transform(rotate(10deg));
    // e.g. -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
}
```

Now, what happens at the moment is that an element with classes translated and rotated just ends up being rotated, as the rotate transform overrides the previous translate transform.

What I'd like to achieve is for the final CSS to look like:

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(10deg);
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this using sass (maybe through the use of variables, or via a mixin)?